# How to disable the recommendation my app on contact info when using VoIP CallKit?

Tags: swift, voip, addressbook

Can I disable or hide my app recommendations on contact info? more precisely, when long press the call/video button.  I do not want to show my app on this actionSheet.

[image: example image]

Other apps like Discord, Slack(and so on) don't show this list, And I wonder how to do this. 
 Any comments will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **supportedHandleTypes** to `.generic` for **CXProviderConfiguration** in-order to hide your app recommendations on contact info.

```
    let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: *YourAppName*)
    configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    configuration.maximumCallGroups = 1
    configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]
```

Then:

```
    var callProvider: CXProvider = CXProvider(configuration: configuration)
```

> When the telephony provider receives an incoming call or the user
> starts an outgoing call, the other caller is identified by a CXHandle
> object. For a caller identified by a phone number, the handle type is
> CXHandle.HandleType.phoneNumber and the value is a sequence of digits.
> For a caller identified by an email address, the handle type is
> CXHandle.HandleType.emailAddress and the value is an email address.
> For a caller identified in any other way, the handle type is
> CXHandle.HandleType.generic and the value typically follows some
> domain-specific format, such as a username, numeric ID, or URL.